# How can I use variables and/or loops to more easily and with less code get the key from an object and set a url based on this?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, foreach, javascript-objects

I have a useEffect in a custom react hook where I want to set the URL-link on a button to be depending on which tag that I get from the user in an object. The User-object is an array with several objects all the with the key "Name", but I only want to get the value from the keys(Name) that equals 'small', 'medium' or 'high' (if they exist on the user-object).

Right now I'm doing this - which works - but I think it must be an easier way by comparing or looping through array or objects and maybe setting the url and the value from "Name" to variables, so that I don't have to use so many lines if it were to become a bigger project, but I can't find a good way with less code that works.

So to be more clear; what I want to do is:
If the user-object contains a value for instance that is called 'medium', I want to set the url to `${mediumUrl}?a=${user.UserID}`.

I use hasTag to see if any values (small, medium, high) even exists, so that I can set it to true or false which decides to show the page or button with the URL at all, since I don't want the page or the button to be shown if the user does not have any of the right values.

I hope this isn't too confusing and please let me know if it is and I can try to clarify. I'm pretty new to JavaScript. Thank you!

```
const [showPage, setShowPage] = useState(true);

    const hasTag = userTags.some(
//UserTag is the interface for the user-tags.
      (tag: UserTag) =>
        tag.Name === 'small' ||
        tag.Name === 'medium' ||
        tag.Name === 'high'
    );

    switch (userTags.some(tag => tag?.Name)) {
      case userTags.some(tag => tag?.Name === 'small'):
        setWheelUrl(`${smallUrl}?a=${user.UserID}`);
        setLoading(false);
        break;
      case userTags.some(tag => tag?.Name === 'medium'):
        setWheelUrl(`${mediumUrl}?a=${user.UserID}`);
        setLoading(false);
        break;
      case userTags.some(tag => tag?.Name === 'high'):
        setWheelUrl(`${highUrl}?a=${user.UserID}`);
        setLoading(false);
        break;
      default:
        setLoading(false);
    }

  if(!hasTag) {
    setShowPage(false)
  }
```

Comment: I doubt this code even works, how can you use this in switch: userTags.some(tag => tag?.Name)

Comment: @vaira there's no need to doubt. You can test it your self, and see that you can use it like that. It's just highly unorthodox. https://jsfiddle.net/g8o3rjfv/2/

Comment: @vaira Yes I've tried the code and it works.

Comment: @Olian04 thanks I learned something new, this could come in handy in a very-very complex situation I guess.

Comment: @vaira I doubt it. Just because something is possible doesn't mean that there is a legitimate use for it :)

Comment: @Olian04 I know, just being optimistic.

Answer (score 1):

We can directly find the desired tag and then use the name property inside it in the switch.

```
    const [showPage, setShowPage] = useState(true);

// should directly find the tag with correct value using 'find' operator
    const tag = userTags.find(
      (tag: UserTag) =>
        tag.Name === 'small' ||
        tag.Name === 'medium' ||
        tag.Name === 'high'
    );

    switch (tag?.Name)) { // no need to calculate in every case
      case 'small':
        setWheelUrl(`${smallUrl}?a=${user.UserID}`);
        setLoading(false);
        break;
      case 'medium':
        setWheelUrl(`${mediumUrl}?a=${user.UserID}`);
        setLoading(false);
        break;
      case 'high':
        setWheelUrl(`${highUrl}?a=${user.UserID}`);
        setLoading(false);
        break;
      default:
        setLoading(false);
    }

  if(!tag) {
    setShowPage(false)
  }
```

Comment: This should work for you